# Drawing over an Image and recording the coordinates of the drawing

Tags: android

I would like to have an image that a user can place points over and record that exact location in relation to the image so it can be shown again where the user placed the marks on the image in the future.

I apologize I find it hard to explain so as an example: suppose there is a square divided into four quadrants.  The user can place a dot in quadrant one and then I want to save the coordinate that relates to quadrant one somewhere so I can 1)reproduce the same image if the user loads it in the future and 2)record in my software somewhere that it was placed in that quadrant/coordinate.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

when you catch the event, you could get the coordinates of the tap by

```
event.getX();
event.gety();
```